# Mypy error when dealing with Generic classes, class variables and staticmethod

Tags: python, mypy, typechecking, type-annotation

I have the following code that replicates an error that I have in my original code:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, ClassVar, Type
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

T = TypeVar("T")

class Formatter(ABC, Generic[T]):
  @staticmethod
  @abstractmethod
  def format(x: T) -> T:
    ...

class MyFormatter(Formatter[T]):
  @staticmethod
  def format(x: T) -> T:
    return x


class FormattableClass(ABC, Generic[T]):
  formatter: ClassVar[Type[Formatter]]
  def __init__(self, x: T) -> None:
    self.x: T = x

class SpecificFormattableClass(FormattableClass[T]):
  formatter = MyFormatter
  def __init__(self, x: T):
    self.x = self.formatter.format(x)
```

Mypy shows the following error in the last line

> Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "T", variable has type "T")

How should I procede to solve it then?

I know it may be from the fact that mypy cannot know that "T" in the Formatter class is the same T as the FormattableClass generic.
A possible solution I came up was simply do the following:

```
class FormattableClass(ABC, Generic[T]):
-  formatter: ClassVar[Type[Formatter]]
+  formatter: ClassVar[Type[Formatter[T]]]
  def __init__(self, x: T) -> None:
    self.x: T = x
```

But mypy complains about another error

> ClassVar cannot contain type variables

Comment: have you considered simply not using a class variable?

Comment: Believe me or not, but your Formatter is not generic right now (maybe semantically, but not from the implementation POV). Static method do not relate to class instance - so usage of type vars bound to generic is highly questionable in those. Let's say I have a `fmt = MyFormatter.format(x)` call somewhere - what's T here? In Python type variables are resolved for instances and not for classes. Remove `Generic[T]` from `Formatter` bases, and things will work as intended.

Comment: Yes, your `Formatter` class is not generic, its **method** `format` is.